# How can we use Assets Catalog Color Sets?

Tags: swift, uicolor, asset-catalog, ios11, xcode9-beta

I usually use custom UIColors on iOS using extensions with Swift, but now with iOS 11/ Xcode 9 we can create Colors Sets. How can we use them?

**Update - Tip**

As @Cœur says we can drag&drop de color, and use it like a UIColor object and a possible solution could be use it as a extension:

[image: UIColor as an extension]

Or as a constant:

[image: UIColor as a constant]

Now I wanna know if we can access them like an UIImage access to an Asset Image or not, like:

```
UIImage(named: "image-name") -> UIColor(named: "color-name")
```

Answer (score 126):

```
UIColor(named: "myColor")
```

Source: [WWDC 2017 Session 237 —— What's New in MapKit](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/237/)

---

Caveat: Your project's *Deployment Target* needs to be set to iOS 11.0.

Comment: This will require Deployment Target = 11.0.

Answer (score 49):

In Xcode 11 press command + shift + L , it will open a snippet , select last one like i showed in image drag and drop .

[image]

Comment: Kudos. Never would have thought to check this menu.

Comment: It's a nice way to add color literal but if we need to change the color a little using the assets, the change will not reflect in the code where the literal was dragged. Thus I am still looking for solutions that use asset name instead and deal with the optional return type of UIColor.

Comment: Perfect Way to Add Color

Comment: very handy tip, Thanks!

Comment: What's the point of using the asset catalog then? You may as well insert the literal in code, because doing this doesn't link the color to the asset catalog, it just pastes a snapshot. Try changing the color in the asset catalog and you'll see your color doesn't change

Answer (score 48):

*(short answer to the question update: there is [`UIColor(named: "MyColor")`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/2877380-init) in Xcode 9.0)*

Answering the original question:

1. you create your color set

[image]

2. you find your color among your snippets and you drag-n-drop it

[image]

3. it will translate to a color literal when looking at the source code:

   `#colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0.6378085017, blue: 0.8846047521, alpha: 1)`

You notice how the values of red, green and blue are different? It's because I defined them using Color Space `Display P3`, but the colorLiteral is using Color Space `sRGB`.

Comment: @elGeekalpha it's a bad practice to edit the question to a different one; see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350309/should-i-edit-my-answer-when-the-asker-edits-the-question or https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions

Comment: I didn't change the question, I just have specified better the implementation I want: How can I use them, but like we usually use Images Assets coz drag&drop is just one alternative solution. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Xcode didn't add `UIColor(named:)`, it's part of UIKit, which is built in to iOS starting with iOS 11. It might seem like a subtle point but it's important. Xcode can't add methods to UIKit.

Answer (score 35):

### Short Version

Add a colour set to an asset catalog, name it and set your colour in the attributes inspector, then call it in your code with `UIColor(named: "MyColor")`.

### Full Instructions

1. In the asset catalog viewer, click the plus button at the bottom right of the main panel and choose **New Color Set**

   [image: New Color Set menu]
2. Click on the white square, and select the *Attributes Inspector* (right-most icon in the right pane)
3. From there you can name and choose your colour.

   [image]
4. To use it in your code, call it with `UIColor(named: "MyColor")`. This returns an optional, so you'll need to unwrap it in most cases (this is probably one of the few cases where a force unwrap is acceptable, given you know the colour exists in your asset catalog).

Comment: This will require Deployment Target = 11.0.

Comment: How can I do it in iOS <= 10

Comment: Good answer.  I wish iOS would make those assets something you could compile against the same way Android does with R.color.myColor.  The new Colors.xcassets approach is definitely better, but still leaves the door open to runtime errors if you mistype a color's name, remove a color without finding all the spots it's used, etc.  Seems like something that should be caught at compile time rather than cause a crash at runtime (I get that you can treat it as optional and not force unwrap it, but then that adds more complexity...so then what was the point?!) :)

Comment: In iOS < 11.0 you need to use an `if #available(iOS 11.0, *) { } else { //Fallback on earlier versions }`, etc. set up.

Answer (score 34):

You need to use [`UIColor(named: "appBlue")`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/2877380-init).

And you can create a function in UIColor extension for simple access.

```
enum AssetsColor {
   case yellow
   case black
   case blue
   case gray
   case green
   case lightGray
   case separatorColor
   case red
}

extension UIColor {

    static func appColor(_ name: AssetsColor) -> UIColor? {
        switch name {
        case .yellow:
            return UIColor(named: "appYellow")
        case .black:
            return UIColor(named: "appBlack")
        case .blue:
            return UIColor(named: "appBlue")
        case .gray:
            return UIColor(named: "appGray")
        case .lightGray:
            return UIColor(named: "appLightGray")
        case .red:
            return UIColor(named: "appRed")
        case .separatorColor:
            return UIColor(named: "appSeparatorColor")
        case .green:
            return UIColor(named: "appGreen") 
        }
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
userNameTextField.textColor = UIColor.appColor(.gray)
```

Comment: Minimum SDKs are: iOS 11.0+, Mac Catalyst 13.0+, tvOS 11.0+, watchOS 4.0

Comment: You could add raw value for `enum AssetsColor: String` and provide names as raw values (e.g. `case yellow = "appYellow"`) so you won't need a `switch`, but just `UIColor(named: name.rawValue)`

Comment: How do you resolve the warning `Value of optional type 'UIColor?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'UIColor'` for these optional return type `UIColor?`? What is the default value that we can provide or what is the best way to handle it?

Answer (score 31):

You can use this way for simple accessing (swift 4 & swift 5)

```
enum AssetsColor: String {
    case backgroundGray
    case blue
    case colorAccent
    case colorPrimary
    case darkBlue
    case yellow
}

extension UIColor {
    static func appColor(_ name: AssetsColor) -> UIColor? {
         return UIColor(named: name.rawValue)
    }
}
```

Using:

```
userNameTextField.textColor = UIColor.appColor(.blue)
```

Answer (score 10):

```
 // iOS
 let color = UIColor(named: "SillyBlue")

 // macOS
 let color = NSColor(named: "SillyBlue")
```

Comment: That URL has nothing to do with asset catalog colors, or colors, or iOS.

Answer (score 7):

For your question if you can access color assets like the image using literal, as of Xcode 10.2 you can type in `colorliteral`, then you can pick the color you want to use that is under your asset manager.

[image: sample snippet]

Comment: Hi just type-in `color literal`  in your editor.
for example:
label.textColor = color literal

Comment: How do you access the color assets like that in Xcode 12.5? I double-clicked the color square "Color Literal" created, then clicked on "Other" in the new pop-up but none of the tabs show the color assets, not even "Color Palettes"'s 5 dropdown options.

Answer (score 3):

In case you experience a delay with colors loading in a Swift Package when using `UIColor(named:)`:

The answers above are totally valid for a regular project but if you are using assets in a swift package, you can see a delay when loading the colors when you use `UIColor(named: "example_name")`. If you use `UIColor(named: "background", in: Bundle.module, compatibleWith: .current)` overload that is targeting the module, the colors load immediately without any delay.

Note: I experienced this on Xcode 12.1.

Answer (score 3):

for swiftUI create a class and name it : Color+extansion and extend Color :

```
import SwiftUI

extension Color {
    static let background = Color("BackgroundColor")
    static let whiteColor = Color("WhiteColor")
    static let blackColor = Color("BackgroundColor")
    static let primery = Color("PrimeryColor")
    static let secondaryColor = Color("SecondaryColor")    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can create extension with func for unwrapping colors from assets and use it with every color in your app

```
extension UIColor {
    static var someColor: UIColor {
        return UIColor.color(name: "SomeColor")
    }

    private static func color(name: String) -> UIColor {
        guard let color = UIColor(named: name) else {
            return .black
        }
        return color
    }
}
```

usage example:

```
UIColor.someColor
```

or

```
someLabel.textColor = .someColor
```

Answer (score 2):

Or, with the SwiftUI [`Color`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/color) structure, you can simply call the [initializer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/color/init(_:bundle:)) with the asset name:

```
Color("background")
```