# Crashing for no apparent reason accessing .xcassets

Tags: swift, xcode, exc-bad-access, ios11

I have an .`xcassets` folder containing Colours. The target membership of the folder is same as my project. As are all the colours inside the folder.

In code I access with `UIColor(named:)` but I get a

```
var colour = UIColor(named: "<#a colour that exists with this name#>")
```

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x8)

I am having same uses trying to access images from a separate .`xcassets` folder.

Colours and Images exist yet Xcode crashes.Its as if the colours and images don't exist but they do.

I have tried removing and re-adding the colours and images buts same useless error each time.

included the backtrace

```
(lldb) bt
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x8)
    frame #0: 0x000000018c3510f0 CoreUI`-[CUINamedColor cgColor] + 88
    frame #1: 0x000000018ed957d8 UIKit`-[_UIAssetManager colorNamed:withTraitCollection:] + 248
    frame #2: 0x000000018e77cda8 UIKit`+[UIColor(UIColorNamedColors) colorNamed:inBundle:compatibleWithTraitCollection:] + 168
    frame #3: 0x00000001022d71b8 MY_APPLICATION_NAME`@nonobjc UIColor.__allocating_init(named:) at ViewController.swift:0
  * frame #4: 0x00000001022d69d4 MY_APPLICATION_NAME`ViewController.pickerView(pickerView=0x0000000103314930, row=0, component=0, view=nil, self=0x000000010330f2b0) at ViewController.swift:117
    frame #5: 0x00000001022d73cc MY_APPLICATION_NAME`@objc ViewController.pickerView(_:viewForRow:forComponent:reusing:) at ViewController.swift:0
    frame #6: 0x000000018e539a30 UIKit`-[UIPickerView tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 616
    frame #7: 0x000000018ed5d6ac UIKit`-[UIPickerColumnView tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 168
    frame #8: 0x000000018e6180e8 UIKit`-[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 668
    frame #9: 0x000000018e61864c UIKit`-[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] + 80
    frame #10: 0x000000018e5f82e4 UIKit`-[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 2140
    frame #11: 0x000000018e602888 UIKit`-[UITableView _cellForRowAtIndexPath:usingPresentationValues:] + 232
    frame #12: 0x000000018e3fdbb8 UIKit`-[UITableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 76
    frame #13: 0x000000018eba84d4 UIKit`-[UIPickerTableView selectRow:animated:notify:updateChecked:] + 352
    frame #14: 0x000000018e5383d4 UIKit`-[UIPickerView _resetSelectionOfTables] + 184
    frame #15: 0x000000018e538258 UIKit`__30-[UIPickerView layoutSubviews]_block_invoke + 6612
    frame #16: 0x000000018e2f2480 UIKit`+[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 104
    frame #17: 0x000000018e53683c UIKit`-[UIPickerView layoutSubviews] + 152
    frame #18: 0x000000018e5392ec UIKit`-[UIPickerView selectedRowInComponent:] + 52
    frame #19: 0x000000018e534d94 UIKit`-[UIPickerView _updateSelectedRows] + 144
    frame #20: 0x000000018e534e44 UIKit`-[UIPickerView didMoveToWindow] + 104
    frame #21: 0x000000018e2e1178 UIKit`-[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 1496
    frame #22: 0x000000018e2e0e68 UIKit`-[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 712
    frame #23: 0x000000018e2e0e68 UIKit`-[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 712
    frame #24: 0x000000018e2e0324 UIKit`__45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke + 156
    frame #25: 0x000000018e2e017c UIKit`-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 796
    frame #26: 0x000000018e2ebd98 UIKit`-[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 1728
    frame #27: 0x000000018e2eafd0 UIKit`-[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 688
    frame #28: 0x000000018e2e8014 UIKit`-[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 272
    frame #29: 0x000000018e3579f8 UIKit`-[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 48
    frame #30: 0x000000018e5471b4 UIKit`-[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 3616
    frame #31: 0x000000018e54bf44 UIKit`-[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1712
    frame #32: 0x000000018e7cb5c8 UIKit`__111-[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:]_block_invoke + 800
    frame #33: 0x000000018ea91bb0 UIKit`+[_UICanvas _enqueuePostSettingUpdateTransactionBlock:] + 160
    frame #34: 0x000000018e7cb22c UIKit`-[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:] + 252
    frame #35: 0x000000018e7cba9c UIKit`-[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability activateEventsOnly:withContext:completion:] + 748
    frame #36: 0x000000018ef15c24 UIKit`__82-[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 260
    frame #37: 0x000000018ef15ac8 UIKit`-[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 448
    frame #38: 0x000000018eca00b0 UIKit`__125-[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:]_block_invoke + 220
    frame #39: 0x000000018ee30290 UIKit`_performActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext + 112
    frame #40: 0x000000018ec9ff60 UIKit`-[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:] + 252
    frame #41: 0x000000018ea91210 UIKit`-[_UICanvas scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 364
    frame #42: 0x000000018e54a688 UIKit`-[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 540
    frame #43: 0x000000018e938c24 UIKit`-[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 364
    frame #44: 0x00000001875e6968 FrontBoardServices`-[FBSSceneImpl _didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 364
    frame #45: 0x00000001875ef270 FrontBoardServices`__56-[FBSWorkspace client:handleCreateScene:withCompletion:]_block_invoke_2 + 224
    frame #46: 0x000000010317d45c libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 16
    frame #47: 0x0000000103189b74 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 268
    frame #48: 0x000000018761ab04 FrontBoardServices`__FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 36
    frame #49: 0x000000018761a7a8 FrontBoardServices`-[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 404
    frame #50: 0x000000018761ad44 FrontBoardServices`-[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 56
    frame #51: 0x0000000184ef8358 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
    frame #52: 0x0000000184ef82d8 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 88
    frame #53: 0x0000000184ef7b60 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 204
    frame #54: 0x0000000184ef5738 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1048
    frame #55: 0x0000000184e162d8 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
    frame #56: 0x0000000186c9cf84 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 100
    frame #57: 0x000000018e34827c UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 208
    frame #58: 0x00000001022e147c MY_APPLICATION_NAME`main at AppDelegate.swift:12
    frame #59: 0x000000018493a56c libdyld.dylib`start + 4
(lldb)
```

To add when I press the little i icon when i hover over the 'colour' variable I get

```
Printing description of colour:
expression produced error: error: /var/folders/vv/y_jj_dx552l3cm59mqq7m2lm0000gn/T/expr1-3f9799..swift:1:80: error: use of undeclared type 'UIKit'
Swift._DebuggerSupport.stringForPrintObject(Swift.UnsafePointer<Swift.Optional<UIKit.UIColor>>(bitPattern: 0x105338210)!.pointee)
                                                                               ^~~~~
```

Comment: sorry forgot it is a iOS 11 beta constructor will update tags

Comment: I am sorry, I see now. I think you might wanna double check if you specified the assets in your target and if you did maybe try initializer with bundle and traitcollection.

Comment: Have you looked here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44397680/how-can-we-use-assets-catalog-colors-sets maybe you are missing something

Comment: @DominikBucher yeah they are in the target