# Type 'UIColor?' has no member ".myCustomColor" Swift 5.0

Tags: swift, colors, assets, uicolor, xcode11.3

I have all my colors in a dedicated color asset. This allows me to define named constants that supports "Any Appearance" and "Dark Appearance". Existing color assets works (previously defined), but if I try to define new ones (eg. myCustomColor) or even copy an existing one then I get:

```
Type 'UIColor?' has no member 'myCustomColor'
```

Sample usage:

```
label.textColor = .myCustomColor
```

I know I can use (tested with newly created color, so no typos):

```
UIColor(named: "myCustomColor")
```

However, I do not want to change this syntax or have different syntax cluttering my code.

I am on Xcode 11.3 (11C29) and using Swift 5. Anyone else having the same issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can we use Assets Catalog Color Sets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44397680/how-can-we-use-assets-catalog-color-sets)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare custom colours in an extension to `UIColor`.

```
extension UIColor {
    static let myCustomColor = UIColor(named: "myCustomColor")
}
```

You can then use this colour as below:

```
label.textColor = UIColor.myCustomColor
```

Comment: You could have just edited your other answer.

Comment: @matt True - unfortunately I’m on mobile and can’t undelete it from here. I shouldn’t have deleted it tbh.

Comment: Thanks Chris, this is the way to go! I actually had a UIColor extension for previously defined values. Problem was that it had mistakenly been moved to a "not so obvious" folder/group, so I failed to see it. It caused me to believe color sets could be used directly in code. All ok now.

Comment: @igunther Great! Glad you got sorted!

Answer (score 0):

There is no “issue” here. A static property `UIColor.myCustomColor`, similar to Apple's `UIColor.systemRed`, was never going to spring magically into existence just because you put a Color set into an asset catalog. If you want such a property you must define it explicitly.

Comment: I am not sure I follow. Currently I have 30 or so colors defined in my colors.xcassets file and they work beautifully. Each "color" has "Any Appearance" and "Dark Appearance" defined so when I switch the UI from dark to normal it just works. So what I am wondering is why new additions fail to compile.

Comment: Oh yes, they "work beautifully" as dynamic colors, but you cannot reference them in code by saying `.nameOfMyColor`. Only an actual UIColor static property can be referenced that way, whether defined by Apple or by you. For example, if you look at this article https://medium.com/developerinsider/xcode-pro-tips-how-to-use-asset-catalogs-to-support-named-colors-8959ab51fd84 it talks about making a color sets asset catalog and how to use them, but it never says you can say `.AppRed` to refer to one — because you can't, and you never could.

Comment: They show up in the pop-up menu of colors in interface builder and in the Colors Library, so you can access them that way; but when you write out the name of a color _in code_, the only way to do so for a Color Set in an asset catalog is by using `UIColor(named:)`.

Comment: Thanks matt! You are also right, there is no "issue". My existing extension was misplaced and failing to see that made me believe in magic" :-)

Comment: Ah yes, the power of positive thinking!