# Swift macOS convert Color to NSColor

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, nscolor

I have a `Color` taken from the `asset`, I need to convert it to `NSColor`.

```swift
Color("backgroundTheme").opacity(0.3)
```

How can I do?

Comment: ```NSColor(Color("backgroundTheme"))``` ?

Comment: @Asperi: Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Color'

Comment: You can also use like this ```NSColor(named: "backgroundTheme")?.withAlphaComponent(0.7)```

Comment: @RajaKishan: This seems to work, thx.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can we use Assets Catalog Color Sets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44397680/how-can-we-use-assets-catalog-color-sets)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSColor` already have a `Color` init.
You can use it like

```
NSColor(Color("backgroundTheme")).withAlphaComponent(0.3)
```

Or you can get color by name
like this

```
NSColor(named: "backgroundTheme")?.withAlphaComponent(0.3)
```

Comment: A curiosity why inside an AppDelegate function I can't read the color correctly.

This changes appearance from light to darkmode, for him it remains light.